# open modal in map function react native

Tags: react-native

i want to create component with some map function for loop in items and when click on any items show details in modal but its not true and modal not toggle by click.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props),
  this.state={
    isModalVisible: false,
  }
};

requestData(){
  return(
    SuggestionData.map(function (i) {
      const _this=this;
        return(
          <View key={i.id} style={styles.ContainerViewMSg3}>
            <ListItem noBorder >
              <View style={styles.ContainerTimer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.ReplayButton} 
                  onPress={()=> _this._toggleModal}>
                    <Text>Click me!</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.ContainerOffer}>
                  <Text style={styles.ItemTimeMSG}>{i.OwnerMsg}:</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ListItem>
        </View>
      )
    })
  )
}

_toggleModal = () =>
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });

render(){
    return({this.requestData()})
}
```

This is the code for my modal

```
<Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
  <View style={styles.ModalView}>
    <View style={styles.yellowView}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress=
        {this._toggleModal}>
        <IconFontAwesome name='close' size={36}
          color={them.white} style=
            {{ marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 210 }}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image source={infoModal} style=
        {styles.infoIconModal}/>
      <Text style={styles.Ensure}>ok?</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ContentModal}>

      <View style={styles.ButtonsModal}>
        <TouchableOpacity style=
          {styles.okButton2}><Text style=
            {{ color: them.green, fontFamily: them.fontName }}>Yes</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style=
          {styles.cancelButton}><Text style=
            {{ color: them.green, fontFamily: them.fontName }}>No</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

could you please help me for this problem

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues to your code.
 1. `SuggestionData.map(function (i) {` change this `SuggestionData.map((i) => {` This will make sure of the context.
 2. `_toggleModal = () =>
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });` replace this with `_toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });}`

So it should be

```
requestData(){
    return(
        SuggestionData.map((i) => {
                return(
                    <View key={i.id} style={styles.ContainerViewMSg3}>
                        <ListItem noBorder >
                            <View style={styles.ContainerTimer}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style= . 
                                    {styles.ReplayButton} 
                               onPress={()=> this._toggleModal
                                } >
                                    <Text>Click me!</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <View style={styles.ContainerOffer}>
                                    <Text style={styles.ItemTimeMSG}> 
                                          {i.OwnerMsg}: </Text>
                                </View>

                            </View>
                        </ListItem>
                    </View>
                )
            })
    )
}
_toggleModal = () => {
  this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
}
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Where's your modal? Can you add that code/logic too?
Also if you add a console.log(this.state.isModalVisible) in `render(){` see if that changing on list click or not.

Comment: in console just print false and not toggle